# remove search box from top and add in main

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I am trying to customize sharepoint online website and trying to remove search box from top of sharepoint site and provide it in website like this
[image]

if this is not possible than i want to redirect my search to my own page from top search box. Please let me know any possible solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of what you're asking for can be accomplished at this time. All search boxes are going to the top of the page, but the suite nav is not something that Microsoft supports manipulating -- any any customizations you would make will eventually break.

As far as redirecting it, that I believe is on a roadmap item to allow you to customize it but is not available, yet.

Answer (score 0):

For modern site page, we can add [React Script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to the page, and add some JavaScript code to move the document elements.

The code below for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
$(function () {         
    myVar = setInterval(moveSearchBox, 300);
});
function moveSearchBox(){
    if($("#O365_SearchBoxContainer").length>0&&$("div[class^='mainHeader'] div[class^='sideActionsWrapper']").length>0){
        $("div[class^='mainHeader'] div[class^='sideActionsWrapper']").append($("#O365_SearchBoxContainer"));
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }   
}
</script>
```